# How do I add more fields when searching?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this functionality to search the product. However, I could only search the name of the product.

**Problem:** How can I implement a search where it will allow me to search either the product name, size, or category?

For now, I was able to search and display the products according to what product name was entered in the `search` field.

For example:

1. it will show all of the products with a category of ML upon entering in the `search` field.
2. It will show all of the products with a size of `M` upon entering `m`or `M` in the `search` field.

Answer (score 1):

PS- I don't have enough reputation to add comments

approach 1-
You can add multiple fields for the filter. A dropdown for sizes and one for the search field for the category.

approach 2-
add a dropdown from which users can select what type of filter they want, and then the search field will work according to that.